# Send packets through a StreamSocket in Scapy has no checksum

Tags: sockets, tcp, scapy

i want to make a 3 way handshake in Scapy with Raw Socket. On Wireshark the SYN packet i send through StreamSocket has no checksum( it's 0).

I tried this way:

```
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
s.connect((IP_ConfigParam.TCP_DEVICE_IP, IP_ConfigParam.TCP_DESTINATION_PORT))
ss=StreamSocket(s)
syn = TCP(sport=IP_ConfigParam.TCP_SOURCE_PORT, dport=IP_ConfigParam.TCP_DESTINATION_PORT, flags="S")
#Recompute packet checksum
dummypacket=IPheader()/syn
del dummypacket[TCP].chksum
dummypacket.show2()
synack = ss.sr1(syn)
```

And this way:

```
del syn.chksum
syn = syn.__class__(str(syn))
```

But none of them is working. In first example the show2() output shows the TCP checksum calculated, but on wireshark when i see the SYN packet has checksum 0.

When i try to print dummypacket[TCP].chksum it shows None. How can i extract chksum field?

Comment: Make up your mind. Is it a stream socket or a raw socket?

Comment: Is a raw socket. The StreamSocket class from Scapy just let me use scapy send functions so it's easier to forge packets.